# PL/pgSQL and minted

Tags: minted

When using Minted to highlight a PL/pgSQL script, I get following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
(File '%pythonpath%/scripts/pygments/formatters/latex.py', line 133, in _get_ttype_name)
```

So I tried to use the PostgresLexer, but when trying to compile, this gives errors because square brackets aren't properly escaped:

```
\begin{minted}[fontsize=\footnotesize,frame=single]{postgresql}
-- Function: dist_calc(bigint[])
-- DROP FUNCTION dist_calc(bigint[]);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dist_calc(nodes_array bigint[])
RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
geom_1 RECORD;
...
\end{minted}
```

Is there a solution for the plpgsql lexer, or is there another lexer I could use to format

Comment: Hi, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) `:)` Your code snippet works flawlessly with me (old TL2011, Pygments 1.5). Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) containing your document class, packages and other definitions? It might help us to track down the error. `:)`