# Minted gets error when encounters a dollar

Tags: minted

I'm using minted to try to list & color some pieces of plpgsql (PostgreSQL's plsql), namely some functions and triggers.
The problem appears when I write the dollars as

```
$$
```

or

```
$BODY$
```

which are needed to specify the body of the function. Here is an example:

```
\begin{minted}{postgresql}


CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_vendite()
RETURNS int
AS

$BODY$
DECLARE
    quantitaV int;
    tot double precision;
BEGIN

    SELECT INTO quantitaV qta
          FROM vendite_ft WHERE id=2'
    RETURN quantitaV;

END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
\end{minted}
```

When I try to compile (I'm using TexShop 3.11 for OS X Lion) I get this error from pygments:

```
*** Error while highlighting:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
   (file "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Pygments-1.5-py2.7.egg/pygments/formatters/latex.py", line 133, in _get_ttype_name)

(./es_progetto.out.pyg)
```

it appears as if that syntax is not supported (ignoring the error and continuing compiling gives a listed code printed and stopped at the first `$BODY$` included, removing the `$BODY$`s from the code gives no error at all).

Am I missing something using minted? How can I circumvent this?

**UPDATE**:
I've found this related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65988/pl-pgsql-and-minted) which makes me wonder if you can reproduce the error or it is just me who gets it.

**UPDATE2**
Here is a mwe that still gets me the error:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{postgresql}

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS dblink;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_vendite()
RETURNS int
AS

$BODY$
DECLARE
quantitaV int;
tot double precision;
BEGIN

SELECT INTO quantitaV qta
    FROM dblink('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5433 dbname=autoricambi 
                 user=foodmart password=foodmart', 
             'SELECT qta, pz_unit FROM vendite_ft WHERE id=2')
    AS t(qta int, pz_unit double precision);

    RETURN quantitaV;

END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE 3**
This is an interesting issue: if I comment the `$BODY$` line with plpgsql comment syle (`'--'`) minted does not give an error but in the output the dollars are substituted with the pound symbol!

[image: dollars to pounds]

can anybody confirm this issue too? can this be related to localization?

**UPDATE 4**
Based on the hypotesis that the pygment lexer is the problem, I tried to use only `$BODY` and it works, the problem lies on the fact that the last dollar is unrecognized. It appears that pygments uses an external lexer for the strings starting with a dollar...

Comment: Please provide a complete, compilable MWE.

Comment: If only I would get a dollar every time `minted` encounters an error… :-)

Comment: Hmm, this smells like a Pygments error. Is your Pygments version up to date?

Comment: I have Pygments 1.5 installed with easy_install with python 2.7 from Apple (take a look at the error). Are you able to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saving your postgre code without commenting out the dollars into `test.pyg` and running

```
pygmentize -l postgresql -f latex -F tokenmerge -P verboptions=  -o test.out.pyg test.pyg
```

(the same as the command line used by `minted` but with `\jobname` replaced by `test`)
produces the error (I am also using Pygments 1.5).

Thus this is a problem with `pygmentize` and not `minted`, and this is probably not the best place to seek help. (Also, I am not familiar with `postgresql` syntax so suggest you also recheck that the dollars are valid!)

On the other hand, with the dollars commented out, the LaTeX output produced by `pygmentize` includes the commands `\PYZdl{}` for the dollars, which `\show\PYZdl` reveals to be

```
\char \`\$
```

and which appear as `£`s on my system too. Executing `\renewcommand{\PYZdl}{\textdollar}` before the `minted` environment addresses that part of the issue. This may be a bug in `minted` but I am unable to diagnose it further as I cannot easily find out where the `\PYZdl` macro definition is originally coming from.

Comment: I don't have the `\PYZdl` command available even after including `minted` and its configuration. I'm using `minted.sty` from https://github.com/gpoore/minted/blob/master/source/minted.sty; I'm on OS X 10.10.1. Pygments version: 2.0.1.

Comment: I've added the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` pragma just before the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` one and it works correctly now.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error today as well. For me the key was to make sure to use correct font encoding:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

The default encoding (using pdfLatex) produced £-symbols.

Comment: See [fontenc vs inputenc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44694).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you @MartinSchröder . That taught me something I'd completely missed. Edited answer accordingly.